# Difference between QueryTimelineSample in jobs API and JOBS_TIMELINE view in information schema in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to plot an accurate time series kind of graph for slot usage of my jobs in bigquery.

Assume a hypothetical scenario where I have 100 slots and I want to see the slot usage of my jobs based on my reservation_id or project_id.

Let us assume a job has run from 1st min to 5th min, and another job has run from 35th to 38th min. Now in my time series, my end goal is to see the slot usage in the last 60 min, if I take the average slot usage view, then I have to divide the totalSlotMs by duration to get the estimated number of slots which might not be the accurate one, and I have to distribute the average number of slots for each job in the duration time range, like for the first job if I got the avg number of slots as 50, I have to distribute it to 1st to 5th min, same for the other job. This might not be the accurate view.

So I started looking at two data sources one is [JOBS_TIMELINE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-timeline) View from information schema, this data source will give each second usage for job, there is another data called source [QueryTimelineSample](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#querytimelinesample) in the jobs API. JOBS_TIMELINE view is solving my use case.

I have taken one query and observed the timeline usage from information schema and from the API response, both are different. My question is whether QueryTimelineSample from API will solve my use case or should I go for the JOBS_TIMELINE view.